# error Invalid Jalali year 3503 when i user angular moment piker

Tags: angularjs, momentjs, angular-moment, angular-moment-picker

i use moment js and moment Jalali js and angular-moment js  , i would use datePicker jalali and i use angular-moment-picker when i use attribute locale="fa" , call me error Invalid Jalali year 3503

my code here :

```
<div
        moment-picker="profilePet.birthday"
        locale="fa"
        format="MM/DD/YYYY"
        ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }">
    click me
```

and error inside the console :

```
Error: "Invalid Jalali year 3503"
```

Answer (score 1):

in order to use Jalali -moment to convert time from Gregorian to Jalali you can simply use this method:

```
 getDate(gregorianDate) {
let recivedDate = this.formatGregorianDate(gregorianDate);
 let Jalali= moment(recivedDate, 'YYYY/MM/DD').lang('en').format('jYYYY/jMM/jDD');
console.log(Jalali);
}
```

but because the format of time maybe can not match you can use this method to find desire format, then use the result of the method to input of convert date:

```
 formatGregorianDate(gregorianDate) {
   var date = new Date(gregorianDate);
   var day = date.getDate();
   var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
   var year = date.getFullYear();
   var fullYear = year + '/' + month + '/' + day;
   return fullYear;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can create a Pipe for Jalali-moment and add this code in NPM, and use it according to the link =>
Install via NPM:

    `npm install jalali-moment -S`

then import in Angular Pipe:

    `import * as moment from 'jalali-moment';`

then Pipe content:

@Pipe({
  name: 'jalali'
})
export class JalaliPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    let MomentDate=moment(value);
    return MomentDate.format("jYYYY/jM/jD");
  }
}


At the end you can look this page :

[https://www.npmjs.com/package/jalali-moment/v/1.0.6][1]


  [1]: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jalali-moment/v/1.0.6
```